# Mixing past and present tenses

Tags: tenses

I am wondering whether a sentence like this is correct:

> I wasn't allowed to work because I am Christian.

Or should it be:

> I wasn't allowed to work because I was Christian.

Should it be all past tense even if they still identify as Christian? Thanks!

Comment: Either works fine here. The second one indeed does leave room for the question whether "they" still identify themselves as Christian but as long as it suffices to leave it there, it's OK to do so— As they say, context is everything. A little caveat: For universal facts such as _The earth is round_, you should always use the *present* version (for obvious reasons.)

Comment: @user405662 The usage is a bit different, though, in the third person if the person you are talking about is someone you no longer know. For instance _"I met a man in Lyme Regis who believed the fossils were only six thousand years old because he was a fundamentalist Christian"_.